# Как можно объявить переменную в SQL?

Tags: sql

Как можно объявить переменную в SQL?

Comment: @Zumrat, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

Если речь идет о запросе, то в начале добавляешь

```
DECLARE @value_name var
```

а в конце

```
Table.name = @value_name
```

Где `@value_name` - это название переменной, `var` -  тип переменной, `Table.name` - название столбца, из которого формируется твоя переменная.